# CSS как-будто заморозили, нельзя его отредактировать

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[Это мой сайт.](https://websockettest1.000webhostapp.com/)
Я недавно добавлял таблицу и настраивал её в css файле. Таблица вставилась, но после этого начало происходить нечто странное: я хотел поменять цвет таблицы, но ничего не произошло, потом я решил вообще удалить настройки таблицы в css, но опять же ничего не произошло. Я решил проверить, css вообще редактируется. Написал обыкновенную строку:

```
<p id"testtext">Подключено </p>
```

А в css я написал:

```
.testtext {
color: red;
}
```

И опять ноль реакции после сохранения и обновления файла на сервере, причём html прогрузился(фраза была) , а css нет(фраза была стандартного цвета). Что делать?
Я пользуюсь FileZilla и Notepad++.

Comment: Отредактировали css и попробуйте обновить страницу  `очистка кэша и жесткая перезагрузка`. Либо при обновлении css попробуйте менять его версию типа `<link href="default.css?v=1.2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />`

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! А где это: "отчистка кеша и жесткая перезагрузка"?

Comment: С заменой версии заработало, спасибо!!

Comment: В хроме при открытой консоли на кружке обновить правой кнопкой и там есть пункты. Либо можно в хроме пробовать Shift+F5 а в ФФ кажется Ctrl+F5